# FFmpeg H264 Lossless Video Sharing

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

A video file need to be transferred for further video processing. Sharing raw video (y4m) seems impossible. I am having two options

1. Encoding video file to h264 with `crf 0` - lossless - file size is huge.
2. Encoding video file to h264 with `crf 17/18` - virtually lossless - file size is manageable.

After the video is shared, it will be re-encoded only once with `crf 22/23` with client info added.

Option 2 seems okay, but the quality should not be degraded on the re-encoding.

Is going with Option 1 and managing huge file is better option than Option 2?

Comment: This is subjective and only you can really answer this with the current amount of info provided. Option 2 degrades the quality, but your requirement is that "the quality should not be degraded". If you can wait for a longer encoding you can add `-preset ultraslow` to your lossless command for more efficient encoding.

Comment: Got it. I hope you are mentioning about `-preset veryslow`

Comment: Yes, you are correct-that's a typo.